# Android Wear - WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Package install failed returnCode -104

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm playing around with getting a custom watch face working, but when I package the app with the mobile apk and install the signed mobile APK onto my phone, I get the following error message in my logcat when the wear apk tries to install onto the watch

```
1149-1159/? E/WearablePkgInstaller﹕ Package install failed com.ptrprograms.wearcustomwatchface, returnCode -104
```

Does anyone know where I can find a list of the return codes so I can figure out what's going on? The only differences I have in my code from the base wear project that's generated by Android Studio are in the manifests:

```
wear manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

mobile manifest:
<activity
        android:name=".CustomWatchFaceActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:allowEmbedded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </activity>
```

Additional info - added the LAUNCHER category intent filter and it installs then, so it looks like watch faces right now may need to be included with a normal app as well, but someone probably has a workaround for that as well.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: For those who find their way in here with similar returnCode errors; https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f76a50c/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add the permissions in the mobile manifest

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: *Below is a new blog post of mine that explains the new Watch Face API in Lollipop.*

http://toastdroid.com/2014/12/10/developing-a-watch-face-for-android-wear-lollipop/

---

Make sure that your mobile and wear modules have the same package name and that the mobile app contains all of the permissions that the wear module needs.  Also, the WAKE_LOCK permission is not required by watchfaces.  You can read more about watchface dev on the blog post I did:

http://toastdroid.com/2014/07/18/developing-watchfaces-for-android-wear/

Comment: Use these links, they have everything you need!

Comment: @MinceMan I am unable to get the Android Wearable app running on the simulator. Wondering if anything special needs to be done a.k.a. do we need to connect a device as well? I was under the impression that simply launching the simulator will get the APK up and running as a watchface too.

Comment: I would recommend using wake locks for watch faces actually. It helps make updates with the screen dimmed

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following 2 permission lines from your wear AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I believe the the intent filter is optional if you only want your app to be a watch face.

Here is a watch sample app I found that you can look at for reference.
https://github.com/kentarosu/AndroidWearAndLIFX

Comment: Actually the issue is that you need those permissions in the mobile manifest file. I already got it working a couple days ago and put out a tutorial :) http://ptrprograms.blogspot.com/2014/07/android-wear-creating-custom-watch-face.html with source https://github.com/PaulTR/AndroidDemoProjects/tree/master/WearCustomWatchFace